# error 1093 updating a table using the aggregate of its data

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has prices in it.  I need to update the price if the value is greater than the average of all the prices.  This is the query I am using:

```
update parts
set price = price*0.85
where price > select avg(price) from parts;
```

I keep getting error 1093: You can't specify target table "parts" for update in FROM clause.  I tried to use (select avg(price) from parts)  as A but I get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use use a subquery in the `WHERE` clause if it tries to use the same table as the main query. You have to join with it instead.

```
UPDATE parts AS p1
JOIN (SELECT avg(price) AS avg_price
      FROM parts) AS p2
ON p1.price > p2.avg_price
SET p1.price = p1.price * 0.85
```

Answer (score 0):

update parts p2
set p2. price = p2.price*0.85
where p2.price > (select avg(p1.price) from parts p1);